# How to remove 5 characters from the end of every column in a table MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop through every row in a table, and remove 5 characters from the end of one column. I have written the following code but it seems to remove 2 characters for some reason.

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'nawd_test', 'password', 'nawd_test');

if ($connection->connect_errno > 0) {
    die ('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM test";  

if (!$result = $connection->query($sql)) {
    die ('There was an error running query[' . $connection->error . ']');
}

//Create an array to hold the values of id's already changed
$ids = [];
$newVals = [];

echo '<p>Fetching rows...</p>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Check / Add the id
    if (in_array($row['id'], $ids)) {
        echo '<p style="red"><strong>Error: Script has repeated itself!</strong></p>';
        break;
    }
    $ids[] = $row['id'];

    $rowName = $row['name'];
    $newName = substr($rowName, -1);
    $newName = rtrim($rowName,$newName);
    $newVals[] = $newName;
}

//Now loop and update
$newValID = 0;
foreach ($ids as &$id) {
    echo '<p>Updating row with ID ' . $id . '</p>';
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE test SET name ='" . $newVals[$newValID] . "' WHERE id=" . $id);
    echo '<p>Column successfully changed "<em>' . $newVals[$newValID] . '</em>"</p>';
    $newValID++;
}

echo '<p style="color: green;"><strong>Script complete!</strong></p>';
?>
```

Comment: can you add you table structure, you can do it from query

Comment: change `$newName = substr($rowName, -1);` to`$newName = substr($rowName, -4);`

Comment: either do it on mysql side, using SUBSTRING() or use mb_substr() in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont do this in php, you can do it with a single sql query:

```
UPDATE test SET name = LEFT(name, LENGTH(name) - 5)
```

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$newName = substr($rowName, -1);
$newName = rtrim($rowName,$newName);
```

into

```
$newName = substr($rowName, 0, strlen($rowName) - 5);
```

With the way you're working, you could never predict how many characters that would have removed at the end.
Minimum 1, maximum the whole word.

Please read the documentation about [rtrim](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) and [substr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: I tried this, added a row with the name of '1234567890' but it has removed all of it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this if you wanna doit inside the query:

```
update table1 set name=substr(name,-5,length(name))
```